# Does OpsHub VSO migration utility support Shelvesets migration?

Tags: opshub

I tried to migrate one sample project to migrate changesets and shelvesets.
I realized the shelvesets has not gone through with migration.

Is this something normal or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: No. As of now, Shelvesets are not supported by the Migration Utility.

Comment: Ups. I was hoping this feature to not force our devs to check-in whatever they have before doing migration. Anyway thanks for the answer.